# How to turn off all secure protection of Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, security

I'm working on a program to detect viruses, so I downloaded some virus samples, but when I copy or delete or read contents of those files in my program, Windows 7 always stop that and make a beep sound.I've turn off all the protections I can found, including Windows Defender, Firewall, UAC. And there is no anti-virus software in my system. I'm already the Administrator. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

[Turn off UAC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Turn-User-Account-Control-on-or-off). It should be prompting you every time you run those virus samples.

Open **User Accounts** by clicking the **Start** button , clicking **Control Panel**, clicking **User Accounts and Family Safety** (or clicking User Accounts, if you are connected to a network domain), and then clicking **User Accounts**.

Click **Turn User Account Control on or off**.   If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

Select the Use User Account Control (UAC) to help protect your computer check box to turn on UAC, or clear the check box to turn off UAC, and then click OK.

[Turn off DEP](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-Data-Execution-Prevention-settings). Open System by clicking the **Start** button, clicking **Control Panel**, clicking **System and Maintenance**, and then clicking **System**.

Click **Advanced System Settings**.   If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

Under **Performance**, click **Settings**.

Click the **Data Execution Prevention** tab, and then click **Turn on DEP for all programs and services except those I select**. Then select the virus samples you're using

Comment: I've turn off UAC..forgot to say that..

Comment: `Then select the virus samples you're using` when I do this, it said that I can't open it..

Answer (score 0):

You say you've already turned off all security systems, but you don't list User Access Control, which is the system responsible for the security popups. Have you turned that off as well? You should find the settings under Control Panel/User Accounts.

Also, try running your anti-virus software as administrator. That way, you've already given it all the privileges it needs, so you won't have to confirm every time. Easiest way to do this is to right-click the icon/executable of your program, and choose "Run as administrator". If you start a command prompt with administrator privileges, all programs started from that command prompt are also given those privileges.

Comment: I've turn off UAC..forgot to say that..